# Symfony2 transtable add query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i've problem with Doctrine and Transtable.

I'd like to add new data to database. My  default language is pl_PL.

My controller:

```
namespace Gogs\CMSBundle\Controller;    
use Gogs\CMSBundle\Entity\Page;

...

public function addAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $page = new Page();
        $page->setName('new');
        $em->persist($page);
        $em->flush();


        $page->setTranslatableLocale('it');
        $page->setName('new ita');
        $em->persist($page);
        $em->flush();

        $page->setTranslatableLocale('en');
        $page->setName('new eng');
        $em->persist($page);
        $em->flush();

        $em->persist($page);
        $em->flush();

        $abc = 'Success';
        return new Response($abc);
    }
```

When open web/app_dev.php/add page, it get me error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Page (name,
>   content, menu, order, icon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   ["new", null, null, null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order, icon)
>   VALUES ('new', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)' at line 1

My Page.php

```
<?php

namespace Gogs\CMSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     */
    private $locale = 'pl_PL';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="menu", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $menu;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order", type="integer", length=32)
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="icon", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $icon;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set menu
     *
     * @param string $menu
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setMenu($menu)
    {
        $this->menu = $menu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get menu
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMenu()
    {
        return $this->menu;
    }

    /**
     * Set order
     *
     * @param integer $order
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setOrder($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get order
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    /**
     * Set icon
     *
     * @param string $icon
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setIcon($icon)
    {
        $this->icon = $icon;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get icon
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIcon()
    {
        return $this->icon;
    }

    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
}
```

I use Symfony 2.1. Could you help me? Where is error?

**Edit:**

I found Error.

I coudn't use word "order" in MySQL. I swap this for 'position'. Additionally, I add 'nullable=true' to every colum in Page.php.

Now, Data "NEW" is into database, but rest ("new eng", "new ita") isn't. Table 'ext_translation' is empty.

New page.php:

```
<?php

namespace Gogs\CMSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 */
class Page implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     */
    private $locale;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="menu", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $menu;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="icon", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $icon;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set menu
     *
     * @param string $menu
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setMenu($menu)
    {
        $this->menu = $menu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get menu
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMenu()
    {
        return $this->menu;
    }

    /**
     * Set position
     *
     * @param integer $position
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setPositionr($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get position
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * Set icon
     *
     * @param string $icon
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setIcon($icon)
    {
        $this->icon = $icon;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get icon
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIcon()
    {
        return $this->icon;
    }

    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
}
```

In Controller I try to add translate for data "NEW".

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //$article = $em->find('Gogs\CMSBundle\Entity\Page', 8 /*article id*/);

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('GogsCMSBundle:Page');

    $article = $repository->find(8);

    $article->setName('my title in eng');
    $article->setContent('my content in eng');
    $article->setTranslatableLocale('en'); // change locale
    $em->persist($article);
    $em->flush();
```

Unfortunally, in table "Page" record 8 has new value and table ext_translation is further empty

**Edit 2:**

I solve my poblem.

In config.yml was missing # Doctrine Extensions Configuration. Now this looks like:

```
    # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
                    default:
                        auto_mapping: true
                        mappings:
                            gedmo_translatable:
                                type: annotation
                                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                                alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                                is_bundle: false

# Doctrine Extensions Configuration
stof_doctrine_extensions:
        default_locale: "%locale%"
        translation_fallback: true
        orm:
            default:
              translatable: true
```